# Where is the folder in wich are stored the application files on Raspbian (idem Program Files on Windows)?

Tags: raspbian

I wonder where applications are installed on `Raspbian` so, anyone knows where is the folder in which are stored the application files on Raspbian `(idem Program Files on Windows)`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct equivalent to `Program Files` on Unix-like systems. Program files are typically installed in `/usr` (managed by the OS/package manager) or `/usr/local`, with data files in `/var` and configuration in `/etc`. Below `/usr` and `/usr/local` are directories `bin` containing executables, `share` containing resources, `lib` containing DLLs, etc.

See the (slightly outdated) [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Applications should be installed under your `$PATH` variable. Do an `echo $PATH` to see its content. Note that this variable can have a different content for different users/scenarios, but if you want to be able to execute an application without typing its path, then it has to be in there.